# How to fire custom event in visual force page and handle it in Aura component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, custom-event

I have a vfpage loaded in LWC using iframe and this LWC is called in a parent Aura component. I have a requirement where I have to fire an custom event in VFpage to send details and handle it in Aura component. My manager rejected the solution I acheived using window.postmessage(). He wanted the solution to be implemented only using Custom event. Please le me know if any workaround for this.

Comment: If you are able to move the VFPage out of the lightning component containment hierarchy and place it in the same lightning page (where lightning component exists), you can make use of lightning messaging service (with few known limitations). But as long as you need it within the component and are using `iframe`, window.postMessage() is the only way to go.

Comment: Hmm... if you are allowed to modify the VF page, perhaps you COULD use the Lightning Message Service to communicate to your Aura component...  check here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/06/learn-moar-lightning-message-service-generally-available-in-summer-20